# Using ngCordova plugins without calling them in app.js?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

My app is looking good, thanks to Ionic. All the core info is there and I'm just adding the frills - email, sharing, media (one of the functions is a metronome) and so on.

I can't get any plugins to work.

I've had success with a previous Ionic app but the plugins were all called from within

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   }
}
```

and indeed the Statusbar plugin seems to working fine and it is called from within there.

I'm using the Side Menu starter with tabs built in btw.

My issue, I suppose, is that I've three controller files.
main_ctrls.js - for the main app
menu_ctrls.js - for the menu pages like feedback and email, analytics
extras_ctrls.js - for the "extra" section with the metronome and so on.

I've put 'ngCordova' as a dependency in each module and called the plugin from within the controller with the ready function. Here is the email controller.

```
angular.module('menu.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('FeedCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
      // is available
      alert('Email is available');
    }, function () {
      // not available
      alert('Email is NOT available');
    });

    var email = {
      to: 'max@mustermann.de',
      cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
      bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
      attachments: [
        'file://img/logo.png',
        'res://icon.png',
        'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
        'file://README.pdf'
      ],
      subject: 'Cordova Icons',
      body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
      isHtml: true
    };

    $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
      alert('Email discarded.');
    });
  })
});
```

I'm testing it on Android (Nexus 4 with Android 5.1) with Chrome inspect and I just get an error saying "Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined". Needless to say, the alerts don't pop up.

This happens with all plugins called from within controllers in this way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be this will help. http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/08/16/Ionic-and-Cordovas-DeviceReady-My-Solution

Comment: I could try that but it seems unnecessary as the plugins don't need to ready as soon as the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are invoking the plugins before the cordova device ready is fired. In my angularjs application I have done the following.
1. Removed ng-app from html and did manual bootstrap through script
2. Added cordova.js file to the dependency. ( As the last dependency. After ng-cordova js)
3. Placed the cordova.js in the same folder as that of the index.html. (No explanation for why. From any other location, simply it was not getting added. May be something specific pertaining to cordova.)
4. Added the following script to the index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}); 

onDeviceReady = function() {
    alert("hello!"); 
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["main"]);
});
};
</script>
```

Here "main" is my main angularjs module. This ensures that the app is loaded only after the device ready event is fired by cordova and all cordova related functions are available. Specific to ionic I donot have anycode. May be the portion where ionic bootstraps the app can be put instead of angular.bootstrap.

My assumptions: you have added the plugins to your cordova project through the command

```
cordova plugin add <plugin-location>
```

Comment: Yes I've added the plugins on the command line and checked they are installed. I'm actually doing a device ready, just an Ionic one and not (document).ready. This is as per the docs at ngCordova.

Comment: What about cordova.js file? Have you added it? Some where deviceready event will be added. You have to check if it is fired.

Comment: Yes, it's added. None of it without it and it's almost working.

Comment: Can you try wrapping it in document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {});

Comment: I've put an alert in the ready function and it fires when you go to the page but the plugin just doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry to break your bubble. Plugins will only work on a real device. Yes you can manually bootstrap the app. But still.. Plugins will only work on device and not on chrome.

Comment: oops... i dont know about chrome.. but for me plugins are very well working on android emulator...

Answer (score 0):

index.html ng-cordova include are okay if you can use ngCrdova plugins in app.js, I think ng-cordova is bad injected across angular dependencies. Try this:

- app.js
- controllers.js

adding ng-cordova to project involves adjusting the module definition files like:

app.js

```
angular.module('startapp', ['ionic','ngCordova','startapp.controllers'])
```

controllers.js

```
  angular.module('startapp.controllers', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaEmailComposer) {

       var email = {
    to: 'max@mustermann.de',
    cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
    bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
    attachments: [
      'file://img/logo.png',
      'res://icon.png',
      'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
      'file://README.pdf'
    ],
    subject: 'Cordova Icons',
    body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
    isHtml: true
  };

 $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
   // user cancelled email
 });

    })
```

Only include ngCordova in app.js app definition.